# RichFaces TreeNode - cannot be cast to javax.swing.tree.TreeNode

Tags: swing, jsf, tree, richfaces

I am trying to use the RichFaces tree implementation. I have subclassed the TreeNodeImpl class - below is my decorator superclass. I am getting the above error. Of course I am not implementing javax.swing.tree.TreeNode - I am implementing org.richfaces.model.TreeNode

```
package com.base.view.tree;

import org.richfaces.model.TreeNode;
import org.richfaces.model.TreeNodeImpl;

import com.iLearn.model.base.Typed;

public abstract class TreeNodeDecorator<T extends Typed> extends TreeNodeImpl implements TreeNode {

    public TreeNodeDecorator(T theData) {
        super();
        setData(theData);
    }

    private T data;
    public abstract String getDisplayString();
    public abstract boolean isLeaf();

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(T theData) {
        data = theData;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return getData().getType();
    }
}
```

here is the xhtml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk"
    xmlns:cust="http://memarden.com">

<link href="CSS/navigation.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<h:body>
    <h3>#{text['organization']}</h3>
    <ui:composition template="template-restricted.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="body_content">
            <div class="sl-title">Manage Schools</div>
            <div class="sr-content">
            <h:form>
                <h:commandButton    class="k-button" 
                                    value="create New Sub Org" 
                                    action="#{manageOrgHierarchy.createNew}"/>
                <rich:tree
                        id="orgTree"
                        value="#{manageOrgHierarchy.rootNodes}"
                        style="width:300px" 
                        selectionType="ajax"
                        selectionChangeListener="manageOrgHierarchy.processTreeSelectionChange"
                        var="node">
                    <rich:treeNode><rich:inplaceInput value="#{node.data.nickName}" defaultLabel="click to edit"/></rich:treeNode>
                </rich:tree>
                <h:commandButton    class="k-button" 
                                    value="create New Root Org" 
                                    action="#{manageOrgHierarchy.createNew()}" 
                                    rendered="#{userSession.isAdmin}"/>
                <h:commandButton    class="k-button" 
                                    value="#{text['save']}" 
                                    action="#{manageOrgHierarchy.save}"/>
            </h:form>
        </div>


        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
Jul 11, 2015 11:49:12 PM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/restricted/memes/manageSchools.xhtml]
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.iLearn.view.tree.OrganizationRichFacesTreeNode cannot be cast to javax.swing.tree.TreeNode
    at org.richfaces.model.SwingTreeNodeDataModelImpl.isLeaf(SwingTreeNodeDataModelImpl.java:91)
    at org.richfaces.component.AbstractTree.isLeaf(AbstractTree.java:441)
    at org.richfaces.component.TreeRange.shouldIterateChildren(TreeRange.java:54)
    at org.richfaces.component.AbstractTree.walkModelChildren(AbstractTree.java:508)
    at org.richfaces.component.AbstractTree.walkModelChildren(AbstractTree.java:526)
    at org.richfaces.component.AbstractTree.walkModel(AbstractTree.java:500)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.TreeEncoderBase.encodeTree(TreeEncoderBase.java:90)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.TreeEncoderFull.encode(TreeEncoderFull.java:41)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.TreeRendererBase.encodeTree(TreeRendererBase.java:85)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.TreeRenderer.doEncodeChildren(TreeRenderer.java:129)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.RendererBase.encodeChildren(RendererBase.java:158)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk.application.ResourceViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ResourceViewHandlerWrapper.java:169)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.iLearn.security.authentication.AccessFilter.doFilter(AccessFilter.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.iLearn.utils.web.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:34)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Jul 11, 2015 11:49:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/ilearn] threw exception [com.iLearn.view.tree.OrganizationRichFacesTreeNode cannot be cast to javax.swing.tree.TreeNode] with root cause
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.iLearn.view.tree.OrganizationRichFacesTreeNode cannot be cast to javax.swing.tree.TreeNode
    at org.richfaces.model.SwingTreeNodeDataModelImpl.isLeaf(SwingTreeNodeDataModelImpl.java:91)
    at org.richfaces.component.AbstractTree.isLeaf(AbstractTree.java:441)
    at org.richfaces.component.TreeRange.shouldIterateChildren(TreeRange.java:54)
    at org.richfaces.component.AbstractTree.walkModelChildren(AbstractTree.java:508)
    at org.richfaces.component.AbstractTree.walkModelChildren(AbstractTree.java:526)
    at org.richfaces.component.AbstractTree.walkModel(AbstractTree.java:500)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.TreeEncoderBase.encodeTree(TreeEncoderBase.java:90)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.TreeEncoderFull.encode(TreeEncoderFull.java:41)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.TreeRendererBase.encodeTree(TreeRendererBase.java:85)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.TreeRenderer.doEncodeChildren(TreeRenderer.java:129)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.RendererBase.encodeChildren(RendererBase.java:158)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk.application.ResourceViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ResourceViewHandlerWrapper.java:169)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.iLearn.security.authentication.AccessFilter.doFilter(AccessFilter.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.iLearn.utils.web.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:34)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Remarkable… posting where you get this error would help tremendously (stacktrace)

Comment: RF 4.5 added Swing tree model to supported models of tree components. Apparently something failed there.

Comment: I created an alternate decorator super class that implements javax.swing.tree.TreeNode This avoids the above error, though I'm forced to implement an Enumerator (the code in the swing class looks old). I am not getting a select event however.

Comment: @BalusC - Should I assume that if I go to RF 4.4, this should work with the RF treeNode? I'll give it a shot

Comment: --- No luck - the previous versions I see is 3.0, or 4.3.7Final. They both give a number of errors when I use them

Comment: @Kukeltje - stack trace posted - hope it helps. I can't believe I'm the first person to have subclassed TreeNodeImpl and gotten this error since 4.5 was implemented? Must be something silly in my code?

Comment: In the stacktrace you can exactely see where in tge RF code it happens. Since the source is open, you can easily check it out and compare with previous versions or create a patch

Comment: I am building my own rather large application. I don't have time to debug and fix my libraries code - to do something like that properly one must take the time to understand the underlying code. Hopefully someone who works with the RichFaces code can make the fix, taking into account the existing design.

Comment: I just need to understand if RichFaces will suit my need, if there is a work around for this bug for me, or if I need to switch to a different library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a bug in RichFaces code, until I hear of a RichFaces developer who says otherwise. I've reimplemented the tree in PrimeFaces, and it is working fine now.